# Mypy considers Tuple[float, Optional[float]] not compatible with Union[float, Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, None]]

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to understand why in the following code:

```py
from typing import Optional, Union

def foo(arg: Union[float, tuple[float, float], tuple[float, None]]) -> None:
    pass

a: float = 1.0
b: Optional[float] = None

foo((a, b))
```

Mypy considers `(a, b)` as incompatible with the signature of `foo`:

```
$ mypy typetest.py 
typetest.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Tuple[float, Optional[float]]"; expected "Union[float, Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, None]]
```

My type annotation suggests `b` could only ever be `None` or `float`, so in practice, I'll only ever pass `tuple[float, float]` or `tuple[float, None]`.

I'm running into this at work, as I'm trying to write a wrapper around `requests.Session` with typeshed's type annotations for requests installed. There, the parameter `timeout` is [annotated](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stubs/requests/requests/sessions.pyi#L75) in the same way as the `arg` param above:

```py
Union[float, tuple[float, float], tuple[float, None]]
```

and I'm trying to pass it something annotated as `Optional[float]` and I just want to know what is the correct thing to do here.

Do I need to explicitly pass `None` when `b` is `None` or `cast` it as `float` when it is not?

I am on Python 3.9.

Comment: @python_user I would have thought that too, but I am assuming there's a reason why it is like that in the `typeshed` library, so I'm erring on the side of me doing something incorrect here.